# 05 changes to 5 when i try to .html() using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery, Following is my code :

http://jsfiddle.net/4bRBV/4/

In console i am getting `05` but inside the div my html changes to `5` only. However, I want to have 05 inside my `div` too. 
Why is this happening and how can I achieve this using jquery?
EDIT - I over simplified the code, my exact code is above.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4bRBV/

Comment: seems like you have oversimplified question code. If results are different then it's not from code shown

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4bRBV/2/
This is my exact code.

Comment: html function called twice ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no else after the if statement thus the .html() function is being called twice.

Updated : [http://jsfiddle.net/4bRBV/10/][1]

```
var second = 0;
function counter(i,n){
    if( i < n-1 ) {
        return ++i;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
function secondinc(){

    second = counter(second,60);

    if( second < 9 ){
        var sec = '0'+second; 
        console.log(sec);
        $('.sec').html(sec);
    }else {
        $('.sec').html(second);
    }

}
var secondfunc = setInterval(secondinc, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening here:

```
if( second < 9 ){
    var sec = '0'+second; 
    console.log(sec);
    $('.sec').html(sec);
}
$('.sec').html(second);
```

If `second` is less than `9`, the value of the div is set twice. First in the if statement, and then immediately after the if statement. Calling the second one in an `else` statement solves the problem:

```
if( second < 9 ){
    var sec = '0'+second; 
    console.log(sec);
    $('.sec').html(sec);
} else {
    $('.sec').html(second);
}
```

Also, change `if( second < 9 ){` to `if( second <= 9 ){`, otherwise it will display `9` instead of `09`.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code as follows :

```
if( second < 10 ){
    var sec = '0'+second; 
    console.log(sec);
    $('.sec').html(sec);
}
else{ 
     $('.sec').html(second);
}
```

Without the else statement, sec is replaced by second anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Can reduce this down to:

```
function secondinc(){    
    second = counter(second,60);
    second=second < 10 ? '0'+second : second; 
    $('.sec').html(second);

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4bRBV/12/)**</kbd>